# Where I can download last version of google play service don't using sdk manager?

Tags: android, google-play

I cant find link to download last version of google play service library android not apk. Any body here can help me to find it ?
Note: I am on internet from mobile.

Comment: Can you use the SDK manager to download just the library or you are trying to get it not from a PC.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get it from mobile not from PC,  because I dont have internet on PC yet. I want primary link to download it.

Comment: See this : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgoogleplayservicesjar.htm

Comment: Thank you to reply. But is it last version ?